# How to get access to URL data in new instance of Angular app

Tags: angular, url

I am building an application with Angular 4 that needs to open data in a new tab. Because this would require loading the entire app again I decided just to make that functionality its own mini-app. The only catch is I need to be able to access the parameters contained within the URL to know what data to display. All the answers I found to this question involve injecting a router and calling something like this:

```
this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
```

This doesn't work for me because it is not passing this data within an app so the instance of the router and Activated Route have no idea where it is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after doing some research I found that I actually needed to inject an instance of the router in main component just so it could accept the URL parameter. Even though it wasn't passed from the same app, using the router to structure the URL parsing still works.